# adding elements to an arrayList on serverside in client/server - application

Tags: java, arraylist, client-server

I have made a client/server application, where the client iterates over some numbers, and send each number to the server. Now I want to add this number to an Arraylist, but each time the package is finished, and another package is started, the number in the first package is lost, so I can not save the number on the serverside - could anybody please help me?

Here is my client

```
public class PingClientstripped {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String ServerName = "localhost";
    int port = 7007;
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ServerName);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String s = Integer.toString(i);
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes(),
                s.length(), IPAddress, port);
        socket.send(request);

    }

}
// socket.close();
}
```

and the Server

```
public class PingServerstripped {

static int j = 0;
int n = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 7007;
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    while (true) {
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
        socket.receive(request);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        calculation(request);

    }
}

public static void calculation(DatagramPacket request) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = request.getData();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bais);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String receive = br.readLine();
    String line = new String(receive);

    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("line printed" + line);
    numbers.add(line);
    System.out.println("Size of the array" + numbers.size());

    String value = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        value = numbers.get(i);
        while (numbers.contains(value)) {
            System.out.println(i);
            duplicates.add(value);
            j++;
        }
    }

    int all = numbers.size();
    int dup = duplicates.size();
    System.out.println("final size of the array" + numbers.size());
    System.out.println("number of duplicates " + j);
    System.out.println("Those were duplicates" + dup);

   }
}
```

Comment: Like Scary Wombat said - the software design is very bad. Before you extend your application, read some java beginners guides to improve your design first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

so that they are class scoped fields not local variables

e.g.

```
static int j = 0;
int n = 0;
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Edit**

In this code, neither numbers not value is changing so the loop will be infinite, maybe use an `if` rasther than a loop

```
     while (numbers.contains(value)) {
        System.out.println(i);
        duplicates.add(value);
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestions.
unfortunately it didn´t solve my problems. It continue to print out a lot of zeroés

Comment: Unless you show what is exactly is printing out, we can not really debug it.

Comment: it simply print out the integer 0 in an infinite loop. One 0 on each line

Comment: Scary Wombat
Thank you very much, you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
private static List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I think if you please the above lines in the class level then the data will be saved even when the control exits from the method.